# AVPlayer and AWS Services Streaming

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, avplayer

I'm attempting to stream videos from AWS S3 bucket.
I uploaded several fils with the "make for everyone" permissions.

I have also created a CloudFront distribution (I just chose my bucket and let all others choices by default).
In a web browser I can download file / read with the adress http://distribution.cloudfront.net/movie1.mov

In my project I have initiated an AVPlayer which takes path from a tableview (like an itune but for movie).
The file for each row is the same as tested in my web browser:
http://distribution.cloudfront.net/movie1.mov for row1
distribution.cloudfront.net/movie2.mov for row2 ...

The player takes well the path and start playing but it freeze always at the same time. I have to pause or advance/back to continue the video.

SO it seems to be a buffer problem.

I would like to know if I use well AWS Cloud Front and how I can resolve the buffer problem.

I didn't find any good tutorials or answers about this.

Thank you for your help.

Regards

Comment: Cloudfront has a distribution setting if the file is for 'downloading' or 'streaming'  the default is downloading.  Can you verify that you switched yours to streaming?   Also did you set the Geographic restrictions on cloudfront so that it uses the servers in the area closest to you?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
For your first question: I didn't have choice between downloading or streaming when I created the distribution. 
Or maybe it's the choice between Web and RMTP.
If that I choose Web. -> I must change to RMTP ?

I didn't fo geographic restrictions. Where can I find it ?

Comment: I found the geographic restrictions and set it up for France only (for now). So If I want to expand my application to EU or USA I must add more countries. That's it ?

Comment: Did you ever get this working?  If so what was the solution?

Comment: No there is still freeze always at the same time. I'm wondering if just put the link of the video from AWS S3 in AVPlayer is a good thing ? AWS S3 only can be used to stream videos ?

Answer (score 0):

did you set the Geographic restrictions on cloudfront so that it uses the servers in the area closest to you?

I meant between web and RMTP in my first comment.  You want web so that is correct.

Now that it is restricted to France, test your videos again and see if their performance is better.

You will want to allow other regions as your usage expands.  Remember different regions have DIFFERENT PRICES for cloudfront.  EU and USA are the same but the other regions can be twice as expensive or more .

http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/pricing/

Comment: Thank you for details.
I have tested with the restrictions but the videos still frozen after few seconds :(

Choosing RMTP will not help ?

Comment: I also tried to open the link:
http://distribution.cloudfront.net/movie1.mov

in vlc but it still slow and freeze around the same time. Any idea ?

Comment: It fails in VLC on your local computer as well?  Are you sure that the file is not damaged?  Try to put the file on your regular web server (not s3) and watch the movie that way for testing.

Comment: Yes the file is not damaged. 
I tried to play this video from the website: 
https://v.cdn.vine.co/r/videos/AA3C120C521177175800441692160_38f2cbd1ffb.1.5.13763579289575020226.mp4

and from my bucket (i downloaded it and uploaded in it). 
From the vine.co, avplayer doesn't freeze but from aws it does .. :(

Any idea ? Or must I change aws for another service ?

Comment: Maybe I have to use a service like wowza to stream from aws s3 no ?

Answer (score 0):

AVPlayer can stall while streaming long videos.

You will need to register observers for the keys playbackBufferEmpty and playbackLikelyToKeepUp

```
[playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"playbackBufferEmpty" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
[playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"playbackLikelyToKeepUp" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```

Then on,

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if (!player)  {
        return;
    }

    else if (object == playerItem && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"playbackBufferEmpty"])  {
        if (playerItem.playbackBufferEmpty) {
            //Other relevant code here, like adding spinner
        }
    }

    else if (object == playerItem && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"playbackLikelyToKeepUp"])  {
        if (playerItem.playbackLikelyToKeepUp)  {
            [player play];
            //Other relevant code here, like removing spinner
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's already implemented as I used the player from here :
https://github.com/piemonte/Player

But it always freeze at the same time.

Any other ideas ?

Comment: Then I dont think this is something to do with the App side part.